# Retrieve selected values of select by it's option group

Tags: arrays, object, iteration

Hope someone can help me out here with a clean code to get this information. I thought there was something already to do retrieve this information in this way.

Multi Select example:

````
<select id="xpto" multiple="" class="" >
   <optgroup label="Product Color" data-label="product-color">
      <option value="black">black</option>
      <option value="blue">blue</option>
      <option value="grey">grey</option>
      <option value="red">red</option>
   </optgroup>
   <optgroup label="size" data-label="size">
      <option value="large">large</option>
      <option value="small"> small</option>
   </optgroup>
</select>```

If user selected "blue","black","grey","large". I would like to retrieve the value of xpto grouped like:

{
color: [blue,black,green],
size: [large]
}

Maybe there is a simple solution on getting this information in this matter or some better way organized.
Having this information group will aloow me to do extra verifications for other stuff.

Thanks
````

Answer (score 0):

```
                $data = new Object();
                $.each($('#xpto').find('option:selected'), (i, v) => {
                    var label = $(v).parents('optgroup').data('label');
                    var nVal = $(v).attr('value');
                    if (!(label in $data)) {
                        $data[label]=[];
                    }
                    $data[label].push(nVal);
                })
```